# Como instalar perspectiva do Java EE no Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

Quero começar a estudar Java para web (Servlets, JSP, EJB, Servlets e JSP). Eu já tenho instalado o Tomcat, o JRE, JDK 7 e o Eclipse Kepler Standard.

Como eu configuro o Eclipse pra adicionar a perspectiva JEE por meio de plugins? Preciso acrescentar a perspectiva do Enterprise Edition pois não quero ter mais de uma IDE instalada em meu computador.

Além da perspectiva do JEE no Eclipse, quais diferenças entre as edições SE e EE exigem mais instalações para eu começar o desenvolvimento? Por exemplo: A JRE e o JDK continuam os mesmos? Cada edição (SE e EE) tem uma JRE e um JDK diferentes?

Comment: Sid se alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida, por favor considere marcá-la como correta. Abraço!

Answer (score 5):

### Não existe apenas uma IDE

Primeiro, existem outras boas opções de IDE para desenvolvimento Java, sendo as mais conhecidas [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) e [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/). Porém, não tenha medo do Eclipse.

### Versão adequada do Eclipse para Java EE

Para desenvolver em Java EE, minha sugestão é ir até a [página de downloads do Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) e baixar a versão ***Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers***. Este é apenas um atalho para ter o Eclipse Standard + JDT (*Java development tools*).

### O Eclipse trabalha com múltiplas perspectivas

Embora tenha recomendado o "Eclipse Java EE", isso não significa que essa versão somente permita criar aplicações Java EE. O Eclipse é um IDE que funciona com plugins.

Uma única instalação pode conter vários deles e você pode facilmente alternar entre os diferentes "ambientes" de desenvolvimento através das chamadas "perspectivas".

Acessando a perspectiva "JavaEE", o Eclipse irá mostrar os painéis comumente usados para desenvolvimento JavaEE.

Por outro lado, você poderia também instalar o plugin [Pydev](http://pydev.org/) e alternar para a respectiva perspectiva para desenvolver em Python.

Enfim, não é necessário ter mais de uma instalação. Só não sobrecarregue o Eclipse com muitos plugins, pois ele pode começar a ficar lento.

### Java SE e Java EE

Na prática, bão há diferença entre desenvolver para Java EE ou Java SE. Você sempre criará classes Java.

O que muda são as APIs utilizadas, isto é, interfaces que você usa para implementar um programa ou classes auxiliares.

A maior diferença é que Java EE geralmente exige dependências adicionais que não vem com o JDK, mas disponíveis através de um Servidor de Aplicação, como JBoss ou Glassfish.

### Servidores de Aplicação

Note que o Tomcat não é um servidor JEE completo, pois ele não disponibiliza nativamente APIs como JTA, EJB, JPA, JSF, etc.

Por causa disso, ele é conhecido como um *Web Container*, isto é, um Servidor de Aplicação Web que somente disponibiliza APIs específicas para web como JSPs e Servlets.

Contudo você pode adicionar manualmente bibliotecas de terceiros para ativar APIs JEE no Tomcat.

### Ajuda adicional

Se tiver dúvidas sobre a instalação e uso básico do Eclipse Kepler, dê uma olhada no meu artigo:

#### **[Instalando, Configurando e Usando o Eclipse Kepler](http://luizricardo.eti.br/2013/11/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-eclipse-kepler/)**

Comment: Obrigado. Nas IDEs, acho que vou ficar com o Eclipse mesmo. Eu testei o tal IntelliJ e achei ele pesado, pouco flexível e estranho demais: Ele demora mais tempo pra inicializar do que o Eclipse, é mais pesado, e eu não gostei do seu Design que foca mais em ser bonitinho do que mostrar as ferramentas prontas. Então, acho que vou usar o Eclipse for Java EE para tudo e importar os meu projetos do Standard pra ele. E sobre o Tomcat: Então, já que eu sou iniciante, seria recomendável eu usar o Glassfish por já ser completo? Porque para o tal Tomcat eu precisaria configurar algumas coisas e tals.

Comment: @sid Depende do que você vai fazer. Se for apenas trabalhar com JSPs e acesso simples ao banco, fique com o Tomcat por enquanto porque ele é mais simples. Por outro lado, se pretende desenvolver profissionalmente, eu iria de Glassfish ou JBoss.

Comment: Entendido. Aliás, pra não criar outra pergunta e poluir a página inicial, aqui vai outra duvidazinha: Esses Servlet Containers são, a grosso modo, Web Servers em Java? Digo, se eles são homólogos em Java para softwares como IIS e Apache HTTP Server. Que, pelo que eu estudei, podem ser chamado de Servidores Web.

Comment: @Sid Pelo meu entendimento não é exatamente isso. Eles podem ser análogos se comparar com Apache + PHP ou ISS + ASP. Servlet Containers significam que eles implementam a API Servlets, mas ainda são muito poderosos se você usar as bibliotecas adequadas. O Spring Framework é o melhor exemplo. Com ele, um Tomcat pode ser tão poderoso quanto um JavaEE Completo para determinados contextos.

Comment: @utluiz, como o Tomcat trabalha? Quero dizer, se ele não disponibiliza as APIs, de onde a aplicação as tira?

Answer (score 1):

Cara, não entendi seu problema com o Eclipse EE. Você vai conseguir trabalhar normalmente (como se estivesse usando a versão Standard) quando quiser. Não há nenhum problema...

Como se trata da sua primeira linguagem, recomendo estudar bastante o paradigma OO e treinar bastante os conceitos básicos da linguagem. Só depois disso acho que vale a pena estudar JSP, Servlets... Até ai você pode usar a versão standard mesmo...

Em ambos casos, recomendo estas apostilas:
Java e Orientação a Objetos: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/

Java para Desenvolvimento Web: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/

Vá com calma que não dá pra aprender tudo em uma tacada só! rs

Boa sorte! :D

Comment: Mas, cara, eu já estudei todo o paradigma de orientação a objeto, eu já conheço todas as regras da sintaxe do Java e já sei mais de 10 Desing Patterns :D. Eu estudo Java há pouco mais de um ano, por conta própria. Eu já conheço a API padrão razoavelmente bem e estou me interessando em áreas pra aplicar o Java, como na Web.