# Não aparece a opção adicionar servidor no eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Estou tentando adicionar o servidor tomcat no eclipse mas não aparece o opção adicionar servers em show view e também não consigo mudar a perspectiva para java EE, alguém pode me orientar?

Comment: Baixa a versão Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers no http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ que provavelmente resolve seu problema

Comment: @Math Sua resposta está correta. Se não tem a view `Servers` é porque não tem o plugin WTP para desenvolvimento web, o qual está presente no Eclipse for JavaEE Developers. Está é uma dúvida muito comum, porque ninguém sabe direito qual Eclipse baixar. Seria interessante você adicionar isso como uma resposta.

Comment: @utluiz me lembrei que algo assim já tinha sido tratado aqui pelo site, não seria talvez mais adequado [fechar como duplicada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8712/3117)?

Comment: Eita, tão votando para fechar como fora de escopo. Discordo.

Comment: @Math Acho que realmente dá para encontrar a resposta lá. Fechei como duplicata.

Comment: Charles, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Marquei sua pergunta como duplicata porque a resposta sobre a perspectiva JEE, sobre a versão do Eclipse e sobre como adicionar o plugin para servidores estão todas na outra questão. Se tiver alguma coisa diferente, deixe um comentário aqui. Se tiver novas dúvidas, fique à vontade para fazer novas perguntas. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, primeiro vamos adicionar um servidor no eclipse indo até:

`Window > Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments > Add...`

Agora que temos nosso servidor adicionado, vamos verificar nossas configurações de perspectiva em:

`Window > Open Perspective > Other...`, na janela que irá abrir deverá ter a `Java EE`. Caso não tenha, provavelmente você está com a versão standard do eclipse.